# What is the random string I am seeing when I use get_query_var?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am setting up an advanced search page with ACF fields with a custom post type in wordpress.

In my example I am sending 'Students' in ?licenseType=Students

[image: Search Example]

I have registered my query_vars

```
 add_filter( 'query_vars', 'software_register_query_vars' );
 function software_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'licenseType';
  return $vars;
 }
```

and set up my pre_get_posts filter

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','software_pre_get_posts');
function software_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
  if ( is_main_query() && $query->get('post_type') == 'uc_software' ) {
    $query->set('nopaging','true');  
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' ); 
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' ); 

    $meta_query = array(); 

    if( !empty( get_query_var( 'licenseType' ) ) ){
    $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => 'software_license_type', 'value' => 
    get_query_var( 'licenseType' ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
    }
// ...
//I will add more fields here...
// ...  
    if( count( $meta_query ) > 1 ){
      $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
    }

    if( count( $meta_query ) > 0 ){
      $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }   
  }
}
```

When I view the query that is being created I see

```
SELECT wp_125_posts.* FROM wp_125_posts INNER JOIN wp_125_postmeta ON ( 
wp_125_posts.ID = wp_125_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( 
wp_125_postmeta.meta_key = 'software_license_type' AND 
wp_125_postmeta.meta_value LIKE 
 '{4d69cec85576e5c23416d1afb6df73c1a4a288f24aff1da852b18ad70b464309}Students{4d69cec85576e5c23416d1afb6df73c1a4a288f24aff1da852b18ad70b464309}' 
) ) AND wp_125_posts.post_type = 'uc_software' AND (wp_125_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
OR wp_125_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_125_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_125_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_125_posts.post_title ASC
```

What is the random string that is being captured along with my query_var? Is there a way I can retrieve my query_var without it? I see the same thing when I use $_GET['licenseType'].

Comment: Maybe gzip? hmmmm

Comment: gzip is a file compression tool? How would that get involved?

Comment: Where and how is your query var populated?

Comment: query_var is populated when my page runs WP_Query and my plugin does the pre_get_posts filter and does    get_query_var( 'licenseType' ),     my url has ....com/?licenseType=Students&...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered on [wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286109/what-is-the-random-string-i-am-seeing-when-i-use-get-query-var)

"This is a symptom of having a % character in your meta query value. Since 4.8.3 % characters are being escaped (actually replaced by a semi random string) and should be unescaped before executing the sql query."

I also found that "when using a meta_compare value of 'LIKE', WordPress automatically wraps the wildcard character ( % ) around the meta_value string."

I changed my compare operator from LIKE to = and the random string is removed.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same situation, but for me changing from `LIKE` to `=` was not an option.

For anyone who still needs to still use `LIKE`, you can unescape those random strings back to `%` using [wpdb::remove_placeholder_escape](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/remove_placeholder_escape/)().